# Avoiding whitespace between tags in Jade template output when pretty printing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, pretty-print

I have to print out an `input` tag and a `label` without any space between the end of one tag and the start of the next... but I also want to pretty-print the rest of the document.

By default — with pretty printing turned on in Jade — I get the following:

```
<input ...></input>
<label ...></label>
```

I want:

```
<input ...><label ...></label>
```

or

```
<input ...></input><label ...></label>
```

The idea from [Jade - Controlling line-breaks in the HTML output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531927/91933) doesn't work because `input` is a self-closing tag.

**Update 1:** I have created the obvious solution using a `mixin` and literal HTML, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: If it's possible to break it into multiple files, you could perhaps make that part a separate file then use the API to turn off pretty for the file(s) that contain that line. You could try post-processing the HTML file to get the desired results. In either case, I'm not sure it would be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

In Razor, I addressed this by wrapping the whitespace with a multi-line comment:

```
    <div>
        <span>No trailing</span><!--
     --><span>space</span>
    </div>
```